# Powershell Inverse replace Regex

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

Powershell 7.0 Script: I want to reverse a regex that I used in `replace`.

I have something like this:

```
$a = $_.BaseName -replace 'REGEX', ''
```

The names here are in this pattern (random are random characters and numbers with different length):

```
random A00B00 random
```

where the numbers are all diffrent. I can use `A[0-9][0-9]B[0-9]` to match what I want, but then, I replace only what I want.

I want that the string after the command is `A00B00` and not `random  random`.

I tried diffrent regex but nothing worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options to achive what you're looking for.

One way to go would be to use regex look around and replace what you not want:

```
'random A00B00 random' -replace '(?<=^).*(?=A\d{2}B\d{2})' -replace '(?<=A\d{2}B\d{2}).+'
```

Or you use a back reference and replace your string with a part of the original string, matched in a regex capture group:

```
'random A00B00 random' -replace '.+(A\d{2}B\d{2}).+','$1'
```